# sqlite where clause returns no rows

Tags: sqlite

sqlite 3.6.13

.schema runs   *yields*

```
CREATE TABLE runs (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
               runname    TEXT DEFAULT 'norun',
               ....
```

executing

```
select runname FROM runs ORDER BY runname DESC limit 10;   *returns*

2015ww27.3c
2015ww27.3b
2015ww27.3a
201528.3c
201528.3b
201528.3a
201528.2z
201528.2y
201528.2x
201528.2s
```

but executing

```
select runname FROM runs WHERE runname = '210528.2y';
```

doesn't fail but doesn't return one row as expected.

I've pulled out most of my hair over this - field is declared TEXT so single-quotes are appropriate to use. What's wrong here?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 0):

You have some chars flipped around. You're asking for a runname that doesn't exist. (At least from what your data says at least.)

EDIT:

Maybe you meant to write

```
20158.2y
```

instead of

```
21058.27
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have trailing spaces or something?

You have the 10 and 01 transposed, I'm assuming that's a typo here, if not that's your issue.

You can also try `where runname like '201528.2y%' if you have some trailing spaces or something.

Answer (score 0):

ach, yes, simple stupid typo. But it got me to thinking... the real problem is with a more complex query, one with a JOIN. Plugging 201528.2y into that query worked as expected but some other values did not. Got me thinking about parent-child relationships. So some digging discovered we have some child rows that somehow no longer have parent rows. DoH!

Thanks to all who replied!

CASE CLOSED

Still-learning Steve